# Matrix multiplication in $\mathcal{M}_n(K)$

Tags: matrices

Let $A=(a_{i,j})_{1\leqslant i,j \leqslant n} \in \mathcal{M}_n(K)$ and $E_{i,j}= (\delta_{k,i}\delta_{l,j})_{1\leqslant k,l\leqslant n}$ (Kronecker delta).

I have to find the general term of the following multiplications : $AE_{i,j}$ and $E_{i,j}A$ ;  but I have some difficulties with the idexing when I do the multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use simply have to use a bunch of indices, I'm afraid. For example,

$$(A E_{ij})_{hk} = \sum_l (A)_{hl}(E_{ij})_{lk} = \sum_k a_{hl}\delta_{il}\delta_{jk} = \delta_{jk}\sum_l a_{hl}\delta_{il}=\delta_{jk} a_{hi}. $$

Answer (score 0):

I think it would better to identify the structure of $AE_{ij}$ first. It would have all its columns equal to zero, except the $j$-th column, which is the $i$-th column of $A$. Now use the notion of delta function to make such a structure, that is zero in every column ($\delta_{l,j}=0$ for $l\neq j$), but the $j$-th column ($\delta_{l,j}=1$ for $l= j$) and put the corresponding multiplier from $A$ in it.

$$ \large AE_{ij}=(a_{k,i}\delta_{l,j})_{k,l}$$